# Best practice for Deploy Node Express application and php application on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, deployment, xampp, port

I have an AWS ec2 instance along with one domain. I want to deploy my express node application and PHP application on the same server without adding a port with the domain.
For PHP deployment I have configured xampp server with a default port of 80.
And my node application runs on port 3000.

Currently, I am accessing the node app using - **mydomain.com:3000**
and for the PHP - **mydomain.com/website**

I wanted to use an express node app without entering the port number. example - mydomain.com

Is there any way to configure it with my given scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to run two different applications on one physical server.

How about approaching the concept of load balancing on one server?

Typically, you can implement this using nginx's reverse proxy and upstream.

For example, if the node server is running on port 3000 and the php server is running on port 4000

In nginx node.mydomain.com is port 3000
php.mydomain.com can send on port 4000.

Comment: Do you have any reference post, how to implement Nginx's reverse proxy?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Comment: nginx knows the name of the incoming request and can use it to configure which server to forward the request to.

For more information, refer to the official nginx website.